# MATLAB accessing conditional values and performing operation in single column

Tags: matlab

Just started MATLAB 2 days ago and I can't figure out a non-loop method (since I read they were slow/inefficient and MATLAB has better alternatives) to perform a simple task.
I have a matrix of 5 columns and 270 rows. What I want to do is:

if the value of an element in column 5 of matrix goodM is below 90, I want to take that element and and subtract it from 90.

So far I tried:
test = goodM(:,5) <= 90;

goodM(test) = 999;

It changes all goodM values within column 1 not 5 into 999, in addition this method doesn't allow me to perform operations on the elements below 90 in column 5. Any elegant solution to doing this?

edit:: goodM(:,5)(test) = 999; doesn't seem to work either so I have no idea to specify the target column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking to operate on elements that have values below 90 as your text in the question reads, rather than `'below or equal to'` as represented by `'<='` as used in your code. So try this -

```
ind = find(goodM(:,5) < 90) %// Find indices in column 5 that have values less than 90
goodM(ind,5) = 90 - goodM(ind,5) %// Operate on those elements using indices obtained from previous step
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
b=90-a(a(:,5)<90,5);
```

For example:

```
a =

   265   104   479    13   176
    26   110   447   208   144
   379   163   179   366   464
   301    48   274   391    26
   429   374   174   184   297
   495   375   312   373    82
   465   272   399   447   420
   205   170   373   122    84
     1   417    63    65   252
   271   277   412   113   500
```

then,

```
b=90-a(a(:,5)<90,5);

b =

   64
    8
    6
```